# Actionscript 2- Multiple event handlers

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have recently bought a template that came with a flash header. I want to implement JavaScript based drop down menus; for this, I will need Flash to communicate with JavaScript.
   The Flash was written in ActionScript 2. I cannot find the code where the hover handlers are taking place. (Any ideas on this?) OR... how to add multiple event handlers in ActionScript 2. In ActionScript 3, I understand (Or think I do), however, converting breaks the application. Can someone please show me how to add another event handler without overriding existing ones in ActionScript 2? Specifically one pertaining to onMouseOver onRollOver. Thank-you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AS2, you can't.  Only one handler at a time can exist for onClick/onRollover/onEnterFrame/onAnythingElse.  This was one of the main reasons that AS3 is so much better suited to a certain class of applications, and one of many reasons why developers (as opposed to designers who code) were so eager to jump to AS3.

Comment: Ok... I've found an alternative way; thank-you for you're reply. I'll leave the question open for another 5 minutes then accept if no-one says otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: @PlagueEditor Good work!  Would you mind sharing the alternative way for the benefit of those who might need to know?

Comment: The alternative was more specific to my problem; however, you are correct and I will share nonetheless.
   Each menu item had Framesets with ActionScript calling the stop function. It is here that I added my code to call JavaScript Dropdown menus. It's even better as it allows me to call the drop downs at a specific time in the item's animation. I should have thought of it sooner.
Thank-you once again for you're help.